# How do I avoid applying spaceless to Django fields?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using `{% spaceless %}` in my base template which helps fix a fair bit of spacing issues while maintaining readability of the template code itself, further compounded because I'm using HamlPy.  However, I have some models with fields containing HTML, which are also 'despaced', leading to some incorrect rendering, e.g.

```
... <em>Some Journal</em> <strong>Issue</strong>, 1695 (2013)
```

where the Journal and Issue number get smashed together.  How can I avoid spaceless being applied to the fields themselves while maintaining it elsewhere?

A dumb hack of trying to prepend the field with `{% endspaceless %}` and after with `{% spaceless %}` just throws errors.

Answer (score 0):

`{% spaceless %}` tag removes only spaces between HTML elements, and **doesn't** remove any spaces between text and elements nor spaces inside text. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless

Knowing that, a simple solution might be to move the space inside one of the HTML elements:

```
<em>Some Journal </em><strong>Issue</strong>
```

Another option would be to use CSS to add the space:

```
.some_context em {
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

or

```
.some_context em:after {
    content: " ";
}
```

Third option might be to use `&nbsp;`:

```
<em>Some Journal</em>&nbsp;<strong>Issue</strong>
```

If "non-breaking" has some unwanted effects, try `&#32;` instead.

Comment: My little code snippet is an example of data I have inside a field, so when I insert it, the space between the `<em>` and `<strong>` tags disappears which is incorrect.

Comment: The sample I have is just one of many possible that could occur as the field is a rendered markdown cache.

Comment: @NickT Then  I guess `{% spaceless %}` just isn't an option. You could theoretically create your own template tag that would ignore spaces around some HTML elements, but you can achieve same effect with CSS. If you know what those elements are. If not, then some re-thinking is probably the only option left...